# ¿Cómo generar un folio consecutivo en una caja de texto?

Tags: java

Quiero generar un folio que sea consecutivo, por ejemplo: `0000001` y cuando se genere un registro pase a `0000002`, esto automáticamente. Anexo el código que tengo; el problema de este es que solo llega al `00000010` y ya no genera el `00000011`, se duplica el 10.

```
 //este es en mi clase
 public String numserie() {

    String serie = "";
    ResultSet rs = Database.result("SELECT max(numserie) from ventas");

    try {
        while (rs.next()) {

            serie = rs.getString(1);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return serie;

}


 //este es en el form
public void generaserie() {
    String serie = acc.numserie();

    if (serie == null) {

        txtNserie.setText("0000001");
    } else {

        int Increment = Integer.parseInt(serie);
        Increment = Increment + 1 ;
        txtNserie.setText("000000" + Increment);

    }

}
```

Comment: Tu código funciona bien, al llegar a 10, devuelve un 00000011, no sera que tu ResultSet siempre devuelve 9 por lo tanto el método que suma 1 a la serie da 10?

Comment: por qué no usar secuencias en tu base de datos?, es más eficiente y está libre de problemas de procesamiento asíncrono

Comment: No encuentro error en tu código, pero ya que estás trabajando con base de datos puedes dejar el autoincrement a la base de datos después que realice el commit en cada insert

Comment: muchas gracias Jframe ya pude solucionarlo, le quite el max a mi sentencia sql